# ubuntu-core for ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-core

will there be an ubuntu-touch image for the supported phones that fully utilizes the newer snap formats?

as far as i have seen the phone architectrue is working with so called click packages.

Is there any plan to transform the phone images to ubuntu-core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the plan and it's in the works. There is no timeline or anything announced yet, but I expected it to be discussed at the next Ubuntu Online Summit: http://summit.ubuntu.com/